# Apply php function to all function arguments

Tags: php, function, arguments

What is good way to apply a php function, such as trim(), to all arguments passed to a function while keeping them cogent for further processing? Say we wanted to trim all arguments passed to a mail function:

```
function my_function($a, $b, $c = NULL, $d, $e = NULL, $f = NULL){
    $a = trim($a);
    $b = trim($b);
    $c = trim($c);
    $d = trim($d);
    $e = trim($e);
    $f = trim($f);

// !!! i'd like something other than n lines of trim()...

// do further functioning on original *now trimmed* arguments...

my_function($to,$subject,$body,$from,$cc,$bcc);
```

func_get_args() and other array type functions aren't ideal because our *trimmed* arguments are unavailable for further action as originally defined. Do we need to use some sort of array then reassemble the original arguments after?

Comment: might be solved using get_defined_vars()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to simply do it like in your code. Any solution to this "problem" would be silly, because in the end you *have* to call `trim` for all the arguments. A silly, but brief, way of doing it would be:

```
function my_function($a, $b, $c = NULL, $d, $e = NULL, $f = NULL){
    foreach (range('a', 'f') as $v) {
        $$v = trim($$v);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: My solution as it handles NULL gracefully!

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick:

```
$args = array_map('trim', func_get_args());
```

**EDIT**

Could do even better (borrowing off Mark baker)

```
list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f) = array_map('trim', func_get_args());
```

Comment: Yes, but our original arguments remain untrimmed. We can 'list' to reassemble the original *now trimmed* arguments, but potential NULL values remain undefined and throw an error...

Answer (score 1):

func_get_args() and array_walk() perhaps?

```
function my_function($a, $b, $c = NULL, $d, $e = NULL, $f = NULL)
    $argArray = func_get_args();
    array_walk($argArray,'trim');
    list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f) $argArray;
    ...
}
```